# how to add a Container inside this code??? Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, return, containers

I have this return on my Widget build and i want to add a Container on top of my screen how can i do that?

```
return RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: refresh,
  child: ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
      controller: controller,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: evsePanels.length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index < evsePanels.length) {
          return evsePanels[index];
        } else {
          return  Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32),
            child: Center(
              child: hasMore
                  ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : const Text('No more data to load'),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
  ),
);
```

Comment: where do you want to add this container?

Comment: What is evesPanels? I understand that it's a List, but what does it contain? You need to wrap the content of `evesPanels[index]` in a Widget such as a Container. If it's text, it's needed to be wrapped in Text widget, if it's an image url, then you need to wrap a NetworkImage widget in the Container and pass the URL to NetworkImage, and so on.

Comment: i want to add the container on top of my screen

Comment: the answer is easily set container as parent of RefreshIndicator. but if it dose not work, you may need add parent widget which you use this widget in it so we can help you better.

Comment: i want to add the code below

Answer (score 0):

```
return Column(
      children: [
        RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: refresh,
          child: ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
    controller: controller,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemCount: evsePanels.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index < evsePanels.length) {
    return evsePanels[index];
    } else {
    return  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 32),
    child: Center(
    child: hasMore
    ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : const Text('No more data to load'),
    ),
    );
    }
    }
    ),
    ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height* 0.1,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 0.1,
          child: Text("Add Widget here"),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: now RefreshIndicator doesnt work anymore screen dont display anything

Comment: Wrap your `RefreshIndicator` widget that's inside the `Column` with `Expanded` widget

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i want to add this code

```
Container(
            height: widget.appController.queryData.size.height/12,
            width: widget.appController.queryData.size.width * (9/10),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: widget.appController.themeController.appWhiteLightColor,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: widget.appController.themeController.appGreyLightColor.withOpacity(0.6),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 1,
                    offset: Offset(0, 2), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
            ),
            child:Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children:[
                  Container(
                    width: widget.appController.queryData.size.width * (7/10),
                    child: searchTextField,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                      color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor,
                      tooltip: 'Search',
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      iconSize: 32 * this.unitHeightValue,
                      onPressed: () {
                        this.evseSearchField = myController.text;
                        showEvsePanels();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          )
```